# Trying to find a Disney/nick film from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, disney

So I was it was around 1996 I saw this film. I can only remember a weird scene where a woman executive is talking to a man. She is a villain. She makes some pun joke, revolves in her chair, and two goblin-like creatures sneak up on the guy and blast him. He turns into a blue goop or gets frozen; I can't remember which.

This scene was very dark for Disney, but it was on around 8pm. It could have been on Nick Tv; I'm not sure. The major themes were corporate control and some resistance with an oddball cast of kids.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds vaguely familiar, my first thought was ["The Secret World of Alex Mac"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108921/), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. My other thought was the Disney movie ["P.U.N.K.S."](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/P.U.N.K.S.), but I'm not sure if that fits what you're looking for either.

Comment: @onewho - I don't recall a female exec in [PUNKS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz-nPpA5WrA)

Comment: Was this live-action or a cartoon? Also, can you describe what the woman executive looked like? Even vaguely should help some.